# FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:8:25: fatal error: ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, iot, esp32, esp8266wifi

These are the header files I am using

```
#include <FirebaseArduino.h> // firebase library
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Servo.h>
```

> Error:FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:8:25: fatal error: ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory

I am using esp32 and selected FireBeetle-ESP32

the code complies properly when I change the board to esp8266(generic) but I want to upload this code on esp32

I looked through the internet and added wifi.h to see it works or not but again same result

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but are you sure the correct include is `WiFi.h` instead of `wifi.h` ?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj i did that still same result